# Rails 5.2: collection_select with has_many through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a setup where an `author` has many `sources` (and visa versa) through `authorships`.

I am working on the source form and would like to have a selection dropdown where a user can select multiple authors to be associated with a given source.

My `author` model looks like this:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :sources, through: :authorships

  def last_first
    "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
  end

  ...
end
```

My `source` model:

```
class Source < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships

  ...

end
```

And my `authorship` model:

```
class Authorship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :source
  belongs_to :author
end
```

I tried this at first:

```
    <%= f.collection_select(:author_ids, Author.all, :id, :last_first, multiple: true) %>
```

But I got this strange error: `Could not find the source association(s) "author" or :authors in model Authorship. Try 'has_many :authors, :through => :authorships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?`

I consulted many SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688872/rails-collection-select-has-many-through), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344096/has-many-through-and-collection-select-rails-form), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239961/rails-has-many-through-and-collection-select-with-multiple), but to no avail.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  The [collection_select documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select) is not much help.

Comment: share your view and controller code

Comment: What about the extra `s` in `author_id` in `f.collection_select(:author_ids,...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with a `collection_check_boxes` like this:

```
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :last_first do |b| %>
      <div class="field form-check" style="display: block">
        <%= b.check_box class: "form-check-input" %>
        <%= b.label class: "form-check-label" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Not a dropdown, but it's functional and saves!